# Cuda copy constant from device to host

Tags: cuda

I'm trying to copy a memory from device to host, but i'm getting the following error:

> CUDA Error 13: invalid device symbol

```
__device__ __constant__ unsigned int cuda_delta = 0;
int delta = 0;
checkCuda(cudaMemcpyToSymbol(cuda_delta, 
                             &delta,sizeof(unsigned int),
                             0,
                             cudaMemcpyHostToDevice)); // work
... // call kernel

// does not work, return  CUDA Error 13: invalid device symbol
checkCuda(cudaMemcpyToSymbol(&delta,
                             &cuda_delta,
                             sizeof(unsigned int), 
                             cudaMemcpyDeviceToHost));
```

Comment: u cannot do that.. The documentation of API says "kind can be either cudaMemcpyHostToDevice or cudaMemcpyDeviceToDevice" .. U can check it [Here](http://developer.download.nvidia.com/compute/cuda/4_1/rel/toolkit/docs/online/group__CUDART__MEMORY_gf268fa2004636b6926fdcd3189152a14.html)

Comment: given that constant memory symbols are read-only on the device, what are you hoping to achieve by copying from a constant symbol?

Comment: @talonmies thanks for the answer, could you please elaborate on this? I don't completely understand why you cannot copy from a read-only constant variable, as you are not modifying its value and this operation should be allowed?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

A symbol references GPU memory, so you can't use *ToSymbol when you want to copy from device to host. For device to host, use `cudaMemcpyFromSymbol`.

```
cudaError_t cudaMemcpyFromSymbol    (   void *  dst,
  const char *  symbol,
  size_t    count,
  size_t    offset = 0,
  enum cudaMemcpyKind   kind = cudaMemcpyDeviceToHost    
)
```

Comment: Oh, I didn't know about cudaMemcpyFromSymbol, the kind parameter confused me, i thought was like cudaMemcpy, but it seems you can only use cudaMemcpyDeviceToHost or cudaMemcpyDeviceToDevice on cudaMemcpyFromSymbol and cudaMemcpyHostToDevice or cudaMemcpyDeviceToDevice using cudaMemcpyToSymbol.